# Is it possible to have a non-empirical realistic view?

Tags: empiricism, realism

Pretty straight forward question - there are two movements throughout modern philosophy that quite often come together - realism and empiricism. I'm wondering if being realistic must assume being empiric, or can realism defy empiricism? And if so, is there a philosopher who went by this view?

Comment: If anything, there is a tension between realism and empiricism, empiricists were generally skeptical about realist claims (extreme examples are Hume and positivists). Empiricist forms of realism are usually weak, e.g. Quine's or Putnam's. Strong forms of realism are usually accompanied by [objective idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_idealism) (platonism is the best known example), currently popular with some physicists, like Tegmark. See also [Structural Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structural-realism).

Comment: @Conifold isn't our science empiric realism? And, I know idealistic empiricism is possible (and quite common with skepticm as you've said), but what about the exact "opposite" - non-empiric realism?

Comment: Quine's and Putnam's views are a variety of scientific realism, but you have to be more specific as to what "non-empiricist realism" means. The common approach is to accept empirically established theories of science as ontological and add something extra along platonist lines. Are you looking for views anti-scientific in some sense? Heidegger is a prominent critic of scientific approach to metaphysics, although I'd hesitate to call him a straight realist. Phenomenology (derived from Husserl) is friendlier to science but advocates additional exploration of reality uncaptured by it.

Comment: @Conifold thanks for suggesting Heidegger and Husserl, haven't thought of them that way. Empirical and non-empirical (at least as far as I know) relates to study of nature, while realism and idealism relates to world views (more precisely, study of consciousness, but that's another matter). A non empiric realist (in my view) would be a realist (i.e. someone with a realistic worldview) that would disagree (partially or fully) on the empiric way of studying (meaning he wouldn't require testable theories, or a postriori experience in order to prove theories). As you've said, much like Husserl.

Comment: I wouldn't call Husserl a realist.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant Neither would I, but some interpret him as a realist pre-transcendental turn, and some later phenomenologists were realists (Scheler, Ingarden, Polanyi). But mostly I was not sure that what OP was looking for was realism exactly.

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions of empiricism and realism, but generally speaking, they are rather in tension. Realist positions are optimistic towards knowledge: they assume that knowledge (or at least some aspects of it) are about an external reality, beyond mere experience. Empiricist positions are about the acquisition or justification of knowledge, which they restrict to experience.

For example, some versions of empiricism have it that no inference can be made from the observable to the unobservable. In this sense, realism is incompatible with empiricism. So the answer to your question is: yes, a realist can defy empiricism, and it actually has to do to be a realist, at least this kind of empiricism: the realist claims that our inferences go beyond experience. All realists go by this view.

Weak versions of realism could be compatible with weak versions of empiricism that merely say that knowledge has it source in experience, but that inferences that go beyond are permissible, or that knowledge must be justified by experience but with a permissive understanding of justification. But some versions of realism can still defy even this weak version of empiricism by assuming that we have some direct intuitive access to first principles or to the fundamental nature of things. This view might not be very popular these days but it used to be quite common: it was held by rationalists and platonists, so to go back to your question, all rationalist and Platonist philosophers actually went by this view.

Comment: I should probably edit that into the question, but look at my comment in my question. We're probably not talking about the same empiricism (and I might be wrong to use this term, in this sense).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss I'm not sure. When you say that our sciences are empirical, this is in a weak sense of empiricism: they claim to be justified by experience, but the justification is rather permissive. So for example noone as ever seen an electron but it is sufficient that there's a contact between our postulates and our observations. This is what you seem to imply in your comments and this corresponds to the last paragraph of my answer: this is compatible with a weak form of realism, typically, a realism that remains provisional concerning what goes beyond experience.

Comment: oh I see. I always referred empiricism (or - only what can be observed can be learned) as science because even though electron isn't physically observed with our eyes, we can observe it by testing and seeing results. Let's say for example, Quantum Theory (or in the more extreme - String Theory) wouldn't be scientifically valid if it weren't testable (hence my reference to Popper's pseudo-science distinction), while still be theoretically real/true. So if science was mere realism without empiricism, it would've accepted, for example, String Theory by now, without the need to wait for a test.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss that's right but in philosophy, there are more strict versions of empiricism (that includes scepticism about science describing reality: our theories are merely empirically adequate) and of realism (for example that there are natural kinds and properties that exactly correspond to the classification of scientific theories) and scientists need not take position on these issues because it is "meta-science". A practicing scientist can be instrumentalist or realist for example. From a philosophical perspective science is just an institutionalised activity with shared norms.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss endorsing a theory, for example quantum mechanics, does not mean believing that the theory is a true description of reality: some scientists might believe that quantum mechanics is currently the best theory not because it's true, but only because it is very efficient and useful. Then they are not realist. So scientific validity doesn't mean realism.

Comment: but science does have clear philosophical view

Comment: @YechiamWeiss well tell that to those physicists who developed quantum Bayasianism (the idea that quantum physics is about degrees of credence concerning measurement events) or those who develop relational physics (the idea that a physical state is not absolute but relative to a perspective). Or to the 19th century scientists against atomism, such as Mach. Scientific theories must be interpreted to become part of a philosophical worldview.

Comment: hmm. OK I hear you. But how can you deny the relation of science to positivism (although obviously nowadays positivism was rejected and instead pragmatism is the ruling view)?

Comment: @YechiamWeiss ok my point was that science does not imply realism. Now perhaps your point is that it implies some sort of empiricism, that reliable knowledge is only acquired or justified in contact with experience? I would agree that there's a relation, the success of science pushes in that direction at least, although one could say that scientific knowledge is only part of knowledge in general (because it only concerns specific controlled domains). Can you tell me how this discussion is important regarding your question? If you think my answer is incomplete or misses the mark I can edit it.

Comment: don't worry, there was nothing wrong with your answer, I just replied to your comments and accidentally started a conversation on a slightly different topic. Though, this conversation seems more related to a different question of mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you accept realism as the theory (very roughly) (a) that some facts, events, states of affairs exist independently of experience, (b) that these facts, &c., can be known, and (c) that they can be known (or can only be known) conceptually and not through experience.

Descartes comes to mind as a candidate for this view. Experience, or 'phenomena' as Descartes sometimes calls it, provides the material for science but as such it explains nothing. On the contrary, it leaves everything to be explained by principles, namely laws, which are formulated by reason.

A clear statement of this position is Descartes, Principles of Philosophy, 1644, 
II, art. 64 : 'The only principles which I accept, or require, in physics are those of geometry and pure mathematics; these principles explain all natural phenomena, and enable us to provide quite certain demonstrations regarding them' ('The Philosophical Writings of Descartes, I, tr. J. Cottingham and others, Cambridge, 2009, 247).

We might want to retreat from Descartes' belief in 'quite certain demomstrations' but he does outline the kind of position you asked about.